# Apparently "blank" cells still counted by COUNTA until updating the cell - is this a bug or feature?

Tags: excel, debugging

I've noticed a behaviour in Excel which doesn't intuitively make sense.

If any formula causes a cell to evaluate as a blank string, such as `=""`, then you copy that cell and paste as value so that the formula disappears - the cell will still count when included in a `COUNTA` formula. Until you press F2 to edit the cell, and then press Enter - then the cell will no longer be counted.

I can understand why `COUNTA` counts cells including a formula, but once you copy and paste a cell as a value, if the formula evaluated to blank, the cell should also be blank, at least intuitively. What's weird is that updating the formula causes the COUNT to decrease. This seems like a bug, but I wanted to put it on here to be sure this wasn't a weird feature I was missing.

Here are the steps I took to reproduce this (also in the image below):

1. Enter ="" into cells A1:A10
2. Select cells A1:A10 and Copy
3. Select cell A1 and Paste as Value
4. Select any cell within the range and press F2
5. Press Enter
6. The count in cell A11 will decrease by one

Alternatively to Step 4, if you select any cell within the range and press Delete, the count will also decrease.

[image]

The count in the image is 7 because I've tested Steps 4 and 5 several times - the count started at 10.

I am using the Office Insider program, so if it is a bug this may be the reason why.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Not a bug. Use `ISBLANK` on a cell - returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and now I can see which cells are blank and which are not. But my question is, why would a cell change whether it's blank or non-blank when you simply press F2 to edit and then press Enter? Nominally, nothing has changed about the status of the cell, so it should show a consistent result every time you edit and press Enter. Of course if you press Delete the cell will become blank, but I'm not sure why updating the cell would make it blank.

Comment: The cell has an empty string in it. If you edit it and press Enter, it no longer does, and is therefore blank.

Comment: Right, so pressing F2 will edit out the "Empty string" essentially, and render the cell blank?

Comment: Effectively, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug.

`=""` returns an empty string, which is not the same as a truly empty cell. Copy/pasting values maintains the empty string.

Editing the cell with <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> effectively renders the cell blank.

Here's an interesting little VBA test for more detail:

```
Sub Test()
    With ActiveCell
        .Formula = "="""""           ' enter ="" in the ActiveCell
        Debug.Print TypeName(.Value) ' returns String

        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Debug.Print TypeName(.Value) ' returns String

        .Value = .Value
        Debug.Print TypeName(.Value) ' returns Empty
    End With
End Sub
```